# NuGet exited with code 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am facing an issue with enabling NuGet package restore. Once I enable package restore, all the projects fails to build correctly with the following error message

> The command ".nuget\nuget.exe" install
>   " \packages.config" -source -Noninteractive -RequireConsent
>   -solutiondir "

I have tried to run the command from command prompt and it worked without errors.

I am using VS2012

Answer (score 5):

I have found that the root cause of the issue is having em dash as part of the project folder name. Once I have removed the em dash from the name, the nuget restore worked without issues.

I have created a bug to the NuGet team and hopefully it will be resolved soon
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/900